# Dividing a board of chipboard

Tags: measurement

Is there a **set of rules** to follow when dividing many(as many as needed) standard 2750mm X 1830mm board of chipboard according to a cutting list to ensure the least amount of waste?

Comment: See http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3194/what-techniques-are-there-to-find-the-optimal-wood-cutting-list-for-a-project